# How I can make this insert in the MySQL Database work?

Tags: c#, mysql, forms, winforms

```
private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conn.Open();

    if (textBox3.Text.Trim() == textBox4.Text.Trim() && IsValidEmail(textBox1.Text))
    {
        MySqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
        comm.CommandText = "INSERT into users(userName, password, email) values(@user,@pass,@mail)";
        MySqlTransaction tx = conn.BeginTransaction();
        comm.Transaction = tx;
        try
        {
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = textBox2.Text;
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = textBox3.Text;
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mail", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = textBox1.Text;
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            tx.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error!");
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what I do wrong here.

Comment: Read about `AddWithValue` parameters as what is you passing - doesn't make sense

Comment: I hope **not at all**. Do. Not. Persist. Passwords.

Comment: And also, _"I don't know what I do wrong here."_ - We neither. Because you didn't include how it fails. I suggest you read through [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Microsoft doc](https://%20%20%20%20https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0), the AddWithValue method require two parameters :

- The parameter name, as you did
- The value itself.

I also emphasize the @Fildor comment, for security and legal resons you should only store hashed passwords [Here is a great article about how to do it](https://code-maze.com/csharp-hashing-salting-passwords-best-practices/).

[And here, why you should do it](https://delinea.com/blog/how-do-passwords-work)